# NSDateFormatter Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, time, nsdateformatter

i am using the following code to get the current time..

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0200"]];

// Set date style:
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

NSString *GMTDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: myDate];
```

My problem is : 
I want the time in HH:MM:SS:(milliseconds if possible)

When i run the project, it displays the date and the right time but it also prints "MESZ" which i assume means Middle European System time in My language.

How od i get rid of MESZ and print the time with miliseconds?

Any help is appreciated

thanks in advance

h4wkeye

EDIT :

All i need now is an advice on how to print the milliseconds as well! Thanks for all your helpful answers

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the "setDateFormat:" of NSDateFormatter with your custom attributes, an explanation of how to use it can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Answer (score 72):

Looks like nobody has answered you about milliseconds... use "S" in your format string, like this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You set one more property for dateFormatter like this

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];
```